# Windows Azure VM SDK version

Tags: azure

My question is related to the Azure tools SDK version installed on the VM itself.

My project uses version 1.6 and so is the machine on azure, if i update the SDK used by visual studio how do i update the SDK installed on the machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question! Simple answer is that you don't have to do that. Fabric controller takes care of that for you when you redeploy your application.

If you unzip the package file (you would need to first rename *.cspkg file to *.zip) and then unzip *.cssx files (again by renaming *.cssx files to *.zip), you will see that all the SDK binaries are bundled into the package itself. So when you redeploy your application, fabric controller takes care of that by picking up appropriate files from the `bin` directory.